# Is there any way to extract Map's values?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I try to extract values from the below data type. `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>,`  The sample data is like this.

1. ("aaa", **Map("bbb",333)**)
2. ("ddd", **Map("ccc",444)**)

Result that I want

```
HashMap 
key : bbb, value : 333 
key : ccc, value : 444
```

I tried

```
mapData.values().stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue))
```

but got failed. Is there any good way to extract the values part as Map in the nested `Map`?

Comment: What has "failed"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `flatMap` your entries of the inner map -

```
Map<String, Integer> output = map.values().stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
mapData.values().forEach(map::putAll);
```

or

```
mapData.values().stream().collect(HashMap::new, HashMap::putAll,Map::putAll);
```